# JavaScript - Storing cross-origin images locally (from XML-url) as blobs for web app

Tags: javascript, xml, image, xmlhttprequest, blob

I am creating a web application for offline use that will display items and images accordingly.

I am fetching the displayed data from an XML-file (shown below) and storing it in an IndexedDB:

```
<product>
    <title>Item Title</title>
    <price>$100</price>
    <description>
         product description
    </description>
    <image-url>
         http://url-to-img.png
    </image-url>
    <sku>12345678</sku>
</product>
```

I have tried converting the images with .JSON as well as XMLHttpRequest, but I recieve the *"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"*-error since the images are stored online (I cannot change the access control on the source server, unfortunately).

I am a bit clueless on how to proceed to be able to store the images locally since I do not have that much of experience in these kinds of projects. How would the best way to tackle this problem be?

Answers are much appreciated.